# Are any civil wars -- other than the American Civil War -- commonly reenacted?

Tags: civil-war

...and if not, what is it that makes people comfortable reenacting the American Civil War?  It would seem grotesque to reenact the Rwandan Civil War or Yugoslavian Civil War, for example.

In particular, what is the most recent civil war that people are comfortable reenacting?

Comment: Those only seem more grotesque than usual because you've associated those "civil wars" with the ethnic cleansing.

Comment: True.  Are there any commonly reenacted civil wars that occurred in the past century?

Comment: Did the American Civil War occur last century? It's 150 years ago since it ended so time is a great healer.

Comment: @RobertRedmond right, hence the question:  are there any commonly reenacted civil wars that occurred, say, after 1900?  Time is indeed a great healer.  Is the American Civil War the most recent civil war that people are comfortable reenacting?

Comment: @Adrian If "after 1900" is the question, please put that in your actual question.

Comment: I think Russian civil war is commonly reenacted.

Comment: This is an interesting question and I wonder if the Civil War veterans would have thought this as weird as re-enacting massacres during WW2. I know that very old veterans of both sides met in the 1930s in a friendly way but perhaps there was a time when such meetings would not have occurred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [English Civil War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War) is popular for [re-enactment in England](http://www.englishcivilwar.org/p/re-enactment.html). Helps that it occurred over 350 years ago though.

[Spanish Civil War 1936-39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Civil_War) seems to be regularly [re-enacted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcvSV_hgFuY)  too but probably not on the same scale as the English or American Civil Wars.

Comment: That's interesting -- I never would have guessed that the Spanish reenacted their civil war.  I'd always thought it was particularly nasty (mass killings on both sides, bombings of cities, etc), and that Spanish people basically didn't talk about it today.

Comment: Yeah and the American Civil War was so gentlemanly with slavery and Sherman's march to the sea. WW2 is regularly re-enacted and that was a lot worse than the Spanish Civil War

Answer (score 7):

In Lviv (Lwow) in Ukraine they re-enact the Polish-Ukrainian civil war of 1918:

http://www.istpravda.com.ua/articles/2012/12/7/102886/

(On the other hand, the "civil war" between Ukrainians and Russian communists
which also began in 1918, still continues, so they do not re-enact it).

It is not completely clear whether the national liberation war in the Western Ukraine against Soviet Union qualifies as a civil war but it is also re-enacted:

http://www.istpravda.com.ua/articles/2012/10/16/97206/

Comment: Is the Russian/Ukranian war actually re-enacted, or is it an ongoing shooting war?

Comment: The current Russian-Ukrainian war is unforunately real.

Comment: I suppose you could call that a "reenactment"...just not a very good-natured one.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Russian Civil War of 1917-1922 is re-enacted very often, see [here](http://www.chernogolovka.ru/news.ru.html?msg=29119) and [here](http://garnizon-a.ru/ru/?idx=444) for example (links are in Russian). The interesting point is that there are many fans from both sides, that actually in heart still support one of the sides. Russia is diverse.
More info can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57.21927j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 3):

The Battle of Lexington and Concord in Massachusetts, of the American Revolution. Technically, our revolution was a civil war.

Answer (score 2):

The Chinese Civil War between the Communists and the nationalists  is [reenacted](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWW7uwB614E) in China.
They are cool and have no problem,  because, one side is regarded bad or evil, and the other good ones or saviours. Hence there is no sympathy clash thing. Hence everybody enjoys the good ones beating the bad ones.
:) chinese  not very good on appropriation,  eh?

There has been great sympathy and admiration for Confederate forces and leaders in America , even after they lost. Because the side was viewed as brave, and deserving a legacy. The victors could not and did not brand the Confederates as dishonorable scoundrels,  blood hungry monsters and cruel war criminals. Don't we see people naming their kids after Confederate generals?
Well, Robert Lee Frost :)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a photo of re-enactment of the [Battle of White Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_White_Mountain)

Since Bohemia was effectively a part of Holy Roman Empire, I'm calling it a Civil War.

[image]